# Jekyll converters error

Tags: compiler-errors, jekyll

First of all, I am new using Sass and Jekyll and I am a little lost.

I am trying to jekyll build but it gives me this error:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'css/main.scss':
                    Undefined variable: "$main-color". on line 15
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Undefined variable: "$main-color". on line 15
```

As you can see in my [Github Repo](https://github.com/IgnaciodeNuevo/ignaciodenuevo.github.io) and in the screenshot below the `$main-color` variable is defined in _sass/utils/_variables.scss and the `css/main.scss` is where I import all `.scss` files.

https://github.com/IgnaciodeNuevo/ignaciodenuevo.github.io/blob/master/Jekyll-converters-error.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### css/main.scss

There is no front matter in this file so it's no converted by jekyll.

```
---
---
/* sass/
```

Once it's generated, we have an error line 22 in base/base, this is because variables are imported after code using them.

Put `@import "utils/variables";` at the top.

We'll then have errors with no existing files. Here I've commented them out.

```
@import "utils/variables";
@import "utils/mixins";
// @import "utils/functions";
// @import "utils/placeholders";

@import "base/base";
// @import "base/reset";
@import "base/typography";
//@import "base/links";

//@import "components/buttons";

// @import "layout/navigation";
@import "layout/header";
@import "layout/footer";
// @import "layout/sidebar";

@import "pages/home";
```

#### _sass/utils/_variables.scss

line 15 : `$border: 3px solid $main-color;` but `$main-color` is only declared on line 57. You must declare a variable before using it.
Moving `$main-color` on a line before 15 solve this error.

We then have errors with `$text-font-stack` and `$code-font-stack`. Add declarations after `$code-font` declaration.

```
$code-font:
        "Source Code Pro",
        "Menlo",
        "Monaco",
        "Consolas",
        "Courier New",
        Courier,
        monospace;

$text-font-stack: $sans-font;
$code-font-stack: $code-font;
```

This solve all errors in current repository code.

Comment: The problem was, this is my first Jekyll + Sass proyect and it was a fork and a refactor from others website

Thanks for your help